# Style a code snippet with css

Tags: css, blogs

Could someone give me a link, a tutorial or an already made css template for styling code snippet to add that feature to my blog ?

I seen examples in numerous blogs, but, now that i am searching for one, i can't put hands on it !

I want to be able to post a code snippet with keyword coloration, line numbers etc..

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT : i know there are some solution like [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) (thanks Developer Art) or [SyntaxHighliter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) but i am on a platform and i can't use Javascript

Comment: If you have a server-side programming language preference (PHP, etc.), please state it. There are client-side and server-side solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[manoli.net](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/) offers an online copy/paste syntax highlighter:

> This tool allows you to format your
>   C#, VB, HTML, XML, T-SQL or MSH (code
>   name Monad) code for publishing on a
>   web site or in a blog.
>
> The output conforms to the HTML 4.01
>   specification and is color-coded to
>   make it easier to read. The colors can
>   be changed by modifying the CSS style
>   sheet. See a sample.

And you may want to check out the [Syntax Highlighter](http://www.codeplex.com/syntaxhighlighter) project on CodePlex (not sure how much activity it still has, though):

> Syntax highlighter converts code text
>   to HTML where common language elements
>   are formatted using style sheet
>   classes such that the coloring scheme
>   can be switched or altered as simple
>   as replacing a CSS file. The primary
>   release ships as an extension for
>   BlogEngine.NET.

Comment: manoli is great, it gives me the css/html and it works well, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is what you're looking for.

You include a bunch of JavaScript and CSS files to your pages and mark page sections that need to be prettified. Pretty much it.

Comment: that's cool, i must say. But i can't embed JavaScript in my blog, i am on a platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are server side solutions for this as well, which of course depend on your server language.  PHP is the ever popular choice for blogs, in which case you could use the equally popular [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) library.